# Are bisulfates and bicarbonates soluble in water?

Tags: solubility

Generally, are bisulfates and bicarbonates soluble in water? 
Specifically, are calcium hydrogen carbonate and magnesium hydrogen carbonate soluble in water?

Comment: [Welcome to chemistry.SE!](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/tour) If you had any questions about the policies of our community, please ‎visit [the help center](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help). Other guys: This isn't necessarily a homework question.

Answer (score 2):

According to it's [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calcium_bicarbonate), calcium bicarbonate is not a known solid compound, but it does exist in solution, presumably prepared by dissolving calcium carbonate and bubbling carbon dioxide through the solution until bicarbonate dominates the following pH-dependent disproportionation:

$$\ce{2HCO3- <=> H2O + CO2 + CO3^2-}$$

It apparently has a solubility of 16.6 g per 100 mL of water at room temperature. which is about a 1 M solution.

[Magnesium bicarbonate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnesium_bicarbonate) similarly exists only in aqueous solution, though it is much less soluble at 0.077 g / 100 mL.

As solids, these salts probably fall victim to the following equilibrium( $\ce{M}$ is a generic divalent metal:

$$\ce{M(HCO3)2 <=> H2O + MCO3 + CO2(g)}$$

The carbon dioxide escapes, preventing the system from ever staying at equilibrium.